# Deploy source only to app servers

Tags: git, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm setting up a new environment with capistrano 3 with a separate database server in a *db* role. This is the specification I'm using:

```
set :stage, "preview"
server 'my-web-server', roles: %w{app web}
server 'my-db-server', roles: %{db}
```

However, it tries to checkout the source on *my-db-server*, which I don't want and doesn't even have `git` installed. How can I stop capistrano from doing this, given that the `deploy` tasks are built-in?

I can workaround it with `ROLES=app,web cap myenv deploy`, but how I can I make it the default so that my team members don't need to worry about it?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Capistrano use a `remote` strategy to fetch the sources from Git, that means the server will try to pull the source code.

I think that what you want is a `local` strategy. In this case, Capistrano can fetch the source code from your machine, then copy the files via scp.

It is configurable via the `deploy_via` property. The right value is `copy`:

http://bu.chsta.be/blog/2013-02-24/capistrano-deployment-strategies-deploy-via-a-copy/

Comment: The problem isn't in the way the code is transferred, it's the roles that the deployment targets. The `remote` strategy is fine for the `app` roles, but what I want is to stop deployment happening at all on the `db` role, since it has no need to access our sources.

Comment: Ok. Then, can we see more of your conf file please? If I read the documentation well, I would use the role command rather than the server command. Like: role :db, %w{my-db-server} (See: https://medium.com/p/ba896a142ac)

Comment: I added the rest of the configuration to the question. Using `role` instead doesn't help, unfortunately